# windows 8 Supported API test FAILED

Tags: windows-8, winrt-xaml, mupdf

i'm working on windows 8 pdf reader i used MUPDF source sample 
it's working fine but when i tried for certification 
it giveing following errors. can any one please tell me how to rectify it

> ◦API GetModuleFileNameW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this
>   application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API GetModuleHandleW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API LoadLibraryExW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API LoadLibraryW in kernel32.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0ChangedStateException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0FailureException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ??0InvalidArgumentException@Platform@@Q$AAA@P$AAVString@1@@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0NotImplementedException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0NullReferenceException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0Object@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0OutOfBoundsException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0OutOfMemoryException@Platform@@Q$AAA@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?Allocate@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPAXI@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ?AllocateException@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAPAXI@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?CreateException@Exception@Platform@@SAP$AAV12@H@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?CreateValue@Details@Platform@@YGP$AAVObject@2@P$AAVType@2@PBX@Z in
>   vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?EventSourceAdd@Details@Platform@@YG?AVEventRegistrationToken@Foundation@Windows@@PAPAXPAUEventLock@12@P$AAVDelegate@2@@Z
>   in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?EventSourceGetTargetArray@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAXPAUEventLock@12@@Z
>   in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?EventSourceGetTargetArrayEvent@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAXI@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?EventSourceGetTargetArraySize@Details@Platform@@YGIPAX@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?EventSourceInitialize@Details@Platform@@YGXPAPAX@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?EventSourceRemove@Details@Platform@@YGXPAPAXPAUEventLock@12@VEventRegistrationToken@Foundation@Windows@@@Z
>   in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?EventSourceUninitialize@Details@Platform@@YGXPAPAX@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?Free@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPAX@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ?FreeException@Heap@Details@Platform@@SAXPAX@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?GetActivationFactory@Details@Platform@@YGJPAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@PAUHSTRING_*@@PAPAUIActivationFactory@@@Z
>   in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?GetIBoxArrayVtable@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAX@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?GetIBoxVtable@Details@Platform@@YGPAXPAX@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?GetIidsFn@@YGJHPAKPBU*_s_GUID@@PAPAVGuid@Platform@@@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?GetObjectContext@Details@Platform@@YGPAUIUnknown@@XZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?GetProxyImpl@Details@Platform@@YGJPAUIUnknown@@ABU_GUID@@0PAPAU3@@Z
>   in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?InitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAJH@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ?ReCreateFromException@Details@Platform@@YGJP$AAVException@2@@Z in
>   vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?ReleaseInContextImpl@Details@Platform@@YGJPAUIUnknown@@0@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?TerminateModule@Details@Platform@@YG_NPAVModuleBase@1WRL@Microsoft@@@Z
>   in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?UninitializeData@Details@Platform@@YAXH@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_FailFast@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_ObjectToString@__abi_details@@YGP$AAVString@Platform@@P$AAVObject@3@*N@Z
>   in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?*_abi_WinRTraiseAccessDeniedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseCOMException@@YGXJ@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseChangedStateException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseClassNotRegisteredException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseDisconnectedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseFailureException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidArgumentException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseInvalidCastException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNotImplementedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseNullReferenceException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseObjectDisposedException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOperationCanceledException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfBoundsException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseOutOfMemoryException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_WinRTraiseWrongThreadException@@YGXXZ in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?__abi_make_type_id@@YGP$AAVType@Platform@@ABU__abi_type_descriptor@@@Z in vccorlib110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0_Lockit@std@@QAE@H@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??1_Container_base12@std@@QAE@XZ in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??1_Lockit@std@@QAE@XZ in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Debug_message@std@@YAXPB_W0I@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Getpfirst@_Container_base12@std@@QBEPAPAU_Iterator_base12@2@XZ in
>   msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Orphan_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXXZ in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ?_Swap_all@_Container_base12@std@@QAEXAAU12@@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Syserror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Throw_C_error@std@@YAXH@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Winerror_map@std@@YAPBDH@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Xbad_alloc@std@@YAXXZ in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Xbad_function_call@std@@YAXXZ in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Xlength_error@std@@YAXPBD@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Xout_of_range@std@@YAXPBD@Z in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _Mtx_destroy in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _Mtx_init in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _Mtx_lock in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _Mtx_unlock in msvcp110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ??0event@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0exception@std@@QAE@ABV01@@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0invalid_operation@Concurrency@@QAE@PBD@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ??0invalid_operation@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ??0scoped_lock@critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@AAV12@@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??0task_canceled@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??1critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ??1event@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??1exception@std@@UAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??1scoped_lock@critical_section@Concurrency@@QAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??1type_info@@UAE@XZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??2@YAPAXI@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??3@YAXPAX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ??_V@YAXPAX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?Alloc@Concurrency@@YAPAXI@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?Free@Concurrency@@YAXPAX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Cancel@_CancellationTokenState@details@Concurrency@@QAEXXZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Cancel@_TaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAEXXZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_DeregisterCallback@_CancellationTokenState@details@Concurrency@@QAEXPAV_CancellationTokenRegistration@23@@Z
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_GetCurrentInlineDepth@_StackGuard@details@Concurrency@@CAAAIXZ in
>   msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_NewCollection@_AsyncTaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@SAPAV123@PAV_CancellationTokenState@23@@Z
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_NewTokenState@_CancellationTokenState@details@Concurrency@@SAPAV123@XZ
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_RegisterCallback@_CancellationTokenState@details@Concurrency@@QAEPAV_CancellationTokenRegistration@23@P6AXPAX@Z0H@Z
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_RegisterCallback@_CancellationTokenState@details@Concurrency@@QAEXPAV_CancellationTokenRegistration@23@@Z
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_ReportUnobservedException@details@Concurrency@@YAXXZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_RunAndWait@_TaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAG?AW4_TaskCollectionStatus@23@PAV_UnrealizedChore@23@@Z
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_Schedule@_TaskCollection@details@Concurrency@@QAEXPAV_UnrealizedChore@23@@Z
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_ScheduleTask@*CurrentScheduler@details@Concurrency@@SAXP6AXPAX@Z0@Z
>   in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type.
>   MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?*_ExceptionPtrCopy@@YAXPAXPBX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?_*ExceptionPtrCreate@@YAXPAX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?*_ExceptionPtrCurrentException@@YAXPAX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this
>   API.
>       ◦API ?_*ExceptionPtrDestroy@@YAXPAX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?*_ExceptionPtrRethrow@@YAXPBX@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?set@event@Concurrency@@QAEXXZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?terminate@@YAXXZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?wait@event@Concurrency@@QAEII@Z in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API ?what@exception@std@@UBEPBDXZ in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _CIatan2 in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _CrtDbgReportW in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _CrtSetCheckCount in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _CxxThrowException in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __CppXcptFilter in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __CxxFrameHandler3 in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __CxxLongjmpUnwind in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __clean_type_info_names_internal in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __crtTerminateProcess in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __crtUnhandledException in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __dllonexit in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API __iob_func in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _aligned_free in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _aligned_malloc in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _amsg_exit in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _calloc_dbg in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _crt_debugger_hook in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _errno in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _except_handler4_common in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _free_dbg in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _hypotf in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>       ◦API _initterm in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDF
>
> ```
> WinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _initterm_e in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _invalid_parameter in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _isnan in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _libm_sse2_acos_precise in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _libm_sse2_cos_precise in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _libm_sse2_log10_precise in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _libm_sse2_log_precise in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _libm_sse2_pow_precise in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _libm_sse2_sin_precise in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _libm_sse2_sqrt_precise in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _lock in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _malloc_dbg in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _onexit in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _purecall in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _setjmp3 in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _unlock in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _vsnprintf in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _wmakepath_s in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API _wsplitpath_s in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API abs in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API atoi in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API atol in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API calloc in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API ceil in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API exit in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fclose in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fflush in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API floor in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fopen in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fprintf in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fputc in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fputs in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fread in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API free in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fseek in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API ftell in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API fwrite in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API getenv in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API longjmp in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API malloc in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API memcpy in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API memmove in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API memset in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API printf in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API qsort in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API realloc in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API sprintf in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API sscanf in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strchr in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strcpy_s in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strlen in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strncmp in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strncpy in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strpbrk in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strrchr in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strspn in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strstr in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strtod in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API strtol in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API tolower in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API vsprintf in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API wcscmp in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API wcscpy_s in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>     ◦API wcslen in msvcr110d.dll is not supported for this application type. MuPDFWinRT.dll calls this API.
>
>     •
>     Impact if not fixed:  Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store
> ```
>
> certification requirement
>
> s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It says right there in your error log:

> Impact if not fixed:  Using an API that is not part of the Windows SDK for Windows Store apps violates the Windows Store
>    certification requirement

This means that either you, or a library that you are using, calls into unsupported APIs.

There is no way around this, except to use *supported* APIs.

The following article gives a list of supported/ unsupported APIs: [Porting Desktop Apps to Windows Store Apps](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/win8devsupport/archive/2012/12/20/porting-desktop-apps-to-windows-store-apps.aspx)