# any one using mupdf in their winrt app

Tags: windows-runtime, winrt-xaml, mupdf

I'm using mupdf component in my Windows 8 app. When I tried to upload it on store it is saying unsupported api. How to avoid this? It is pointing to mupdf references file.
When I remove that dll file my app is not running.

Here is my error code

[windows 8 Supported API test FAILED](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18259668/windows-8-supported-api-test-failed)

Answer (score 1):

The Git repository for MuPDF includes source for building on winRT and there are project files in the platform/winrt directory. While this is relatively new, we believe that this all works, if you know differently you should probably open a bug report.

Please note that there is only 1 developer with a build and test system for this, so be patient if posting bugs specific to winRT.

Answer (score -1):

[Issues with Windows App Certification Kit](https://github.com/MishaUliutin/MuPDF.WinRT/issues/6)

Comment: then how to overcome it

Comment: Can you please check that you use the latest version of Windows App Certification Kit ? Latest is v2.2

Comment: i' using the latest version of certification kit then also same result What to do